# Mysql: select by date intersection, not between

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an ordering system. In db I have table with blocked dates for ordering system (when customer wants to turn it off for some reason like vacation).
Ordering system allows to order in time period for next four weeks from actual date.

As input I have in PHP `$startDT` and `$endDT`
Each blocking in db have its `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns

Problem is with long-term blockings (e.g. month), when valid_from and valid_to are out of time period for create order.

[image]

For short-term and mid-term blockings nicely works this code:

```
SELECT * FROM `vk_blocking` WHERE (`valid_from` BETWEEN '$startDt' AND '$endDt') OR (`valid_to` BETWEEN '$startDt' AND '$endDt')
```

But in shown long-term (ID:3), there is on `valid_from` or `valid_to` between `$startDt` and `$endDt`

How to ask MySQL to return also for long-term period? Is there something like

```
SELECT * FROM `vk_blocking` WHERE DATERANGE(`valid_from`, `valid_to`) INTERSECTS DATERANGE($startDt, $endDt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved with:

```
SELECT * FROM `vk_blocking` WHERE `valid_from`<= $endDt AND $startDt<= `valid_to`
```

This ensures that both ranges have at least one day in common.

Comment: True - although I prefer to keep the comparisons consistent.

Comment: Oh, I'm ashamed... I was not able to see so easy way. Thanks a lot, sir.